# Restrict field edit access

Tags: opportunity, permissions, security, restriction

My org has OWD as Private for opportunities. I have a specific requirement where one user needs to be able to edit 3 custom fields in all opportunities , but not other fields should be editable. No restrictions should be added to opportunities they own but for opportunities they don't own they should just be able to edit 3 custom fields.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi , does this post answer your query [How to allow edit access to for certain record types only](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247009/how-to-allow-edit-access-to-for-certain-record-types-only?rq=1) ?

Comment: Hi @SubratSrivastava, it does not. 
Opportunity object is already set to private, we want a user to be able to modify only 3 custom fields in opportunities they don't own, but no restrictions on opportunities they own.